# I need loop to do until all elements of array are equal to 0

Tags: python

Here is my code, it's randomly generated one of four numbers (1,2,3,4) and turns right left or up and down if consider array as a board, starting point is room [0][0]. It stops after changing one element of array to 0 but I need it to do until all elements are equal to 0, Thanks!

```
import numpy
import random
N = 2
M = 2
time = 0
room = numpy.ones((N, M), dtype=int)
print(room)

i = 0
j = 0


while room.all() != 0:
    turn = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4])
    if turn == 1 and i > 0:
        print("up")
        i = i - 1
        room[i][j] = 0
        time += 1
    elif turn == 2 and i < N - 1:
        print("down")
        i = i + 1
        room[i][j] = 0
        time += 1
    elif turn == 3 and j > M - 1:
        print("right")
        j = j + 1
        room[i][j] = 0
        time += 1
    elif turn == 4 and j < 0:
        print("left")
        j = j - 1
        room[i][j] = 0
        time += 1
    else:
       turn = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4])
       print("hit the wall")

    print(room)
```

Comment: `while np.sum(room) != 0:`

Comment: @TBurgis it can be misleading if array elements are negative

Comment: Very true. As can the use of `any` proposed below. -1 is `True` in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html) method checks whether all elements of your array are truthy (in this case, unequal to zero), so the condition in the `while` loop becomes `False` once there is a single zero in `rooms`.

What you actually want to check is whether [`any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html) element of `rooms` is truthy (here, unequal to zero).

You can use `while rooms.any(): ...` instead (and omit the comparison to `!= 0`).

Comment: Thanks @timgeb, problem was solved by using the any() function

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can approach the problem:

**First:** As suggested by @timgeb:

```
while room.any():
```

**Second:** To use `np.count_nonzero` to check if there is any non-zero value in the array. Then use this condition in the `while` loop

```
while np.count_nonzero(room) > 0:
```

HOWEVER, when I use either of these conditions, two elements become 0 and two remain 1 and I end up in a never ending loop. That means, the problem is somewhere in your implementation of your indices.

That being said, now knowing two ways to check for non-zero elements, you need to inspect your code for implementation error.

Comment: Note that `count_nonzero` won't be lazy, in contrast to `any`.

Comment: @timgeb: You mean it will be slower than `any`?

Comment: I mean that `any` stops as soon as it finds a non-zero element. `count_nonzero` keeps iterating over the array to count all non-zero elements. Therefore I expect it to be noticeably slower for large arrays.

Comment: @timgeb: You are right. But that would apply only to a single iteration, right? So I guess the difference would be negligible.

Comment: `count_nonzero` is called every time the `while` condition is checked, this might be more than one iteration. `count_nonzero` is not wrong, but I prefer to use lazy operations when possible!

Comment: The second solutions also useful, and it is slower ) thank you guys